# Не работает карусель

Tags: javascript

Не работает карусель.
Пишу по учебнику, но не получается.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var showSlides = slideIndex;

function plusSlides(n){
 showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n){
 showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n){

 var i;
 var slides = getElementsByClassName(mySlides);
 var dots = getElementsByClassName(dot);


 if (n > slides.length){
  slideIndex = 1;
 }
 if (n < 1) {
  slideIndex = slides.length;
 }
 for (i=0; i < slides.length; i++){
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 for (i=0; i < dots.length; i++){
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active","");
 }

 slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
 dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.slider {
 max-width: 100px;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
}

.prev, .next {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: auto;
 margin-top: -22px;
 padding: 16px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: .6s ease;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
 right: 0;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.textimg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 color: red;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 8px 12px;
}

.dot {
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 13px;
 height: 13px;
 margin: 0 2px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
 background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
 -webkit-animation-name: fade;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-name: fade;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade{
 from{opacity: .4}
 to{opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
 from{opacity: .4}
 to{opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\asdas\css.css">
 <script src="D:\asdas\main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="slider">
 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1/3</div>
  <img src="D:/page2/img/img9.jpg" style='width: 100%'" alt="o">
  <div class="textimg">text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="slides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2/3</div>
  <img src="D:/page2/img/img8.jpg" style='width: 100%'" alt="o">
  <div class="textimg">text</div>
 </div>
 <div class="slides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3/3</div>
  <img src="D:/page2/img/img6.jpg" style='width: 100%'" alt="o">
  <div class="textimg">text</div>
 </div>
 <a onclick="plusSlides(-1)" class="prev">&#10094</a>
 <a onclick="plusSlides(1)" class="next">&#10095</a>
</div></br>
<div style='text-align: center;'>
 <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
 <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
 <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Если здесь запустить ваш код, сразу выдается ошибка «getElementsByClassName is not defined"». Где эта функция «getElementsByClassName»? Возможно вы свой код здесь  не полностью написали. Всего вам доброго!

Comment: есть такая не ври

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1).** Я нашел ваш учебник и код, теперь все работает:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x350/00BFFF/FFFFFF?text=1" alt="">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x350/90EE90/FFFFFF?text=2" alt="">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x350/FFA500/FFFFFF?text=3" alt="">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div> <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a> </div>
<br>
<div style="text-align:center"> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> </div>
```

---

**2).** Еще я сам решил написать для вас карусель, на нативном JavaScript, она больше похожа на настоящую карусель, и интереснее той, что в вашем учебнике, пожалуйста:

```js
"use strict";

var slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
var sliderWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(slider).width);
var sliderItems = slider.querySelector(".slider__items");
var sliderItemList = slider.querySelectorAll(".slider__item");
var sliderItemActive = slider.querySelector(".slider__item_active");

var sliderNavNext = slider.querySelector(".slider__nav-next");
var sliderNavPrev = slider.querySelector(".slider__nav-prev");

var sliderDotActive = slider.querySelector(".slider__dot_active");

var sliderItemsMarginLeft = parseInt(getComputedStyle(sliderItems).marginLeft);

slider.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Отслеживаем клики по слайдеру
  var target = event.target;

  if (target == sliderNavNext) {
    // Если клик был по кнопке «Следующий слайд»
    if (
      sliderItemList[sliderItemList.length - 1].classList.contains(
        "slider__item_active"
      )
    )
      return;

    sliderItemActive.classList.remove("slider__item_active");
    sliderItemActive = sliderItemActive.nextElementSibling;
    sliderItemActive.classList.add("slider__item_active");

    sliderItemsMarginLeft -= sliderWidth;
    sliderItems.style.marginLeft = sliderItemsMarginLeft + "px";

    sliderDotActive.classList.remove("slider__dot_active");
    sliderDotActive = sliderDotActive.nextElementSibling;
    sliderDotActive.classList.add("slider__dot_active");
  }

  if (target == sliderNavPrev) {
    // Если клик был по кнопке «Предыдущий слайд»
    if (sliderItemList[0].classList.contains("slider__item_active")) return;

    sliderItemActive.classList.remove("slider__item_active");
    sliderItemActive = sliderItemActive.previousElementSibling;
    sliderItemActive.classList.add("slider__item_active");

    sliderItemsMarginLeft += sliderWidth;
    sliderItems.style.marginLeft = sliderItemsMarginLeft + "px";

    sliderDotActive.classList.remove("slider__dot_active");
    sliderDotActive = sliderDotActive.previousElementSibling;
    sliderDotActive.classList.add("slider__dot_active");
  }

  if (target.classList.contains("slider__dot")) {
    // Если клик был по кнопке «Точка»
    if (target.classList.contains("slider__dot_active")) return;

    sliderDotActive.classList.remove("slider__dot_active");
    sliderDotActive = target;
    sliderDotActive.classList.add("slider__dot_active");

    var sliderDotList = slider.querySelectorAll(".slider__dot");

    for (var i = 0, length1 = sliderDotList.length; i < length1; i++) {
      if (target == sliderDotList[i]) {
        sliderItemActive.classList.remove("slider__item_active");
        sliderItemActive = sliderItemList[i];
        sliderItemActive.classList.add("slider__item_active");
      }

      if (sliderDotList[i].classList.contains("slider__dot_active")) {
        sliderItemsMarginLeft = -sliderWidth * i;
        sliderItems.style.marginLeft = sliderItemsMarginLeft + "px";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.slider {
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider__items {
  width: 9999px;
  transition: margin .3s;
}

.slider__item {
  float: left;
}

.slider__img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider__dot {
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
}

.slider__dot_active {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__items clearfix">
    <div class="slider__item slider__item_active"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x350/00BFFF/FFFFFF?text=1" alt="" class="slider__img"></div>
    <div class="slider__item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x350/90EE90/FFFFFF?text=2" alt="" class="slider__img"></div>
    <div class="slider__item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x350/FFA500/FFFFFF?text=3" alt="" class="slider__img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__nav">
    <button type="button" class="slider__nav-prev">Предыдущий слайд</button>
    <button type="button" class="slider__nav-next">Следующий слайд</button>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__dots">
    <button type="button" class="slider__dot slider__dot_active"></button>
    <button type="button" class="slider__dot"></button>
    <button type="button" class="slider__dot"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Здесь все довольно просто. Я написал комментарии, надеюсь принцип работы будет вам понятен. А если нет, пожалуйста, напишите комментарий, и возможно, я более подробно прокомментирую код.

---

**3).** Также, позволю себе оставить полезную ссылку на счет JS карусели:

- [learn.javascript.ru#карусель](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)

**Учитесь!**

Comment: Огромная благодарность вам!

Comment: @Yaroslav Potapenko Благодарю и вас, за обратную связь! Правда, мне за мой ответ кто-то минус поставил ) В следующий раз, пожалуйста, сразу давайте ссылку на учебник. **Всего вам Yaroslav доброго!**

Answer (score 1):

Вы перепечатываете код "из учебника" с ошибками.

```
//var showSlides = slideIndex;

...

var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
```